# Are there any vulnerabilities or security risks in using an old legacy log4j.jar Version 1.2?

Tags: java, security, jvm, log4j, legacy

Our software provider delivers batch jobs implemented in java using log4j.jar
(version 1.2; the major version number of the class files in the jar is 45, which corresponds to JDK 1.1)
as their logging framework.

My suggestion to use a more recent version of log4j.jar was rejected with the following argument:
That's not OUR software, that's just open source that we are using and furthermore: it works! so there is no need to change it.

Are there any strong security arguments against:
Using old classes running within a (according to actual knowledge) 'secure' and modern jvm-runtime?

Comment: Your title says specifically log4j 1.2, but then the body says "old classes". Plenty of old classes have serious security problems; many don't.

Comment: What features of log4j do you use? Just logging to plain text file or also logging to a server with open sockets?

Comment: Did you try looking at the public documentation for log4j? The answer is right there.

Comment: Hi, chrylis, ok, my title is more specific than the question in the body, that's right!
Furthermore your answer (Plenty have...many don't) is correct. Thanks!
I'm fishing for a concrete crank in the specific case of -say-... a runtime environment >= openjdk version "1.8.*"
versus class files with major version number 45, especially those in log4j.jar Version 1.2.
My intention is not to hack the software, but to have a valid strong argument against that '...no need to change...'

Comment: Hi, Robert, I use that batch for logging to plain text file but that software also logs into an Oracle-DB.
Does that count as a server with open sockets?
There is at laest one class that imports and uses both 'Category' and 'Socket':  

`import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import org.apache.log4j.Category;

public final class SocketServer extends Thread
{`

Comment: @AAcchhiimm: using Log4j 1.2 as a network client has no known vulnerabilities. Using it as a server for other Log4j 1.2 clients (`ServerSocket` class) is affected by [CVE-2019-17571](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-17571/)

Comment: Hi boneill, the only answer I found [there](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html) is:  

"Vulnerabilities reported after August 2015 against Log4j 1.x were not checked and will not be fixed. Users should upgrade to Log4j 2 to obtain security fixes"  
Upgrade or using the [Log4j 1.x bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/migration.html) is also not possible for me.

Comment: Perhaps the question needs to be rephrased? Based on what's there right now, the answer to the question is "yes.".  Is your concern that somehow the class format has changed? That when the old classes are loaded the JVM itself becomes broken? If this is your question, then the answer is "no". The classes themselves won't break the JVM, but don't use the insecure features of the older log4j. You need to investigate this more closely to be sure.

Comment: @piotr-p-karwasz: Thanks a lot! This is the best and most helpful answer! 
But sorry, it was my first question and I still do not know how to make your comment an answer ?